# Special character issue in python

Tags: python

To support special character in latex we should put single slash before special character(ex: \& ),But python inserts 2 slashes if i replace with single slash (\&).

```
input1 = "managing & director #"
changed_val = input1.replace("&","\&").replace("#","\#")

print changed_val
output:-managing \& director \#
```

If I print the variable it shows single slash but value inside variable includes 2 slashes (at end).

Please advise how to just add a single slash in python so that I can use this string with special character in latex

Or anything in replace of latix

Answer (score 4):

It shows as 2 slashes because Python also uses the slash to indicate special characters, so to show a slash in a variable, it needs to show a slash in front of it.

Here's an interactive session as an example:

```
>>> s = "a string"
>>> s
'a string'
>>> print s
a string
>>> s = "a \\string"
>>> s
'a \\string'
>>> print s
a \string
>>> len(s)
9
```

Bottom line: you don't have a problem.  To confirm, check then length of the string.

Comment: Maybe using a raw string could be useful too here!

Comment: Yes, When I am checking the length its showing two only. But when this special char is being used by latex then its creating issue. Its not accepting two \ with &. Please advise

Comment: I will use raw string ,Thomas Orozco. If it does not work then I will ask help from u guys., Thanks for your time .

Answer (score 0):

Run this to see what is happening:

```
>>> print changed_val
managing \& director \#
>>> assert changed_val == r'managing \& director \#'
>>> changed_val
"managing \\& director \\#"
>>> print repr(changed_val)
"managing \\& director \\#"
```

When you type `changed_val` into the console, it's equivalent to typing `print repr(changed_val)`. `repr` is also the reason the quotes appear.

Comment: Hi Eric, I understand this. I want to save these in my db with single slash only as I am using that value in latex. And latex does not allow double slash . Is it possible ?